# to get a list of bools, .contain()

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i do a list for bools in javascript. im doing a validation so i can have a list of bools and at the end i want to check that list if it contains any errors. im not sure how to add to the varable `validations_errors` (like a list). Plus i dont know how i can check if that list contains any true values.

what i got so far is this

```
var validation_errors;

            if (!validateForm($(this))) {
                validation_errors = false; //here i want to add the it to a list
                var $input_container = $(this).parents('.input');
                $input_container.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            }

    //this is something what i want to do like (this code is c# based)
    if (validation_errors.contains(true)){
    // do some actions
    }
```

**EDIT**
list of bools = list of true & false

Comment: what is a list of bools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var validation_errors = [];
.
.
.

    if (error) validation_errors.push(true)

if (validation_errors.length > 0) ...
```

If you want to store true or false so you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find which test failed:

```
if (validateForm($(this))) validation_errors.push(false);
else {
  validation_errors.push(true);
  var $input_container = $(this).parents('.input');
  $input_container.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
}

var notvalid = validation_errors.indexOf(true);
if (notValid !=-1) alert("The form #"+(notvalid+1)+" failed")
```

Answer (score 1):

validation_errors = []; // DECLARATION

validation_errors.push( newBool ); // adding a new val to the array.

And then you can regularly iterate through the array at the end.

If I were you though, I would try something like this...

validation_errors = false; // declaration

Within the loop

If ( !newBool ) validation_errors = true;

And at the end

If( validation_errors ) //we failed

So you won't need a whole array and a second loop.

Edit : cellphone typing

Answer (score 0):

Make `validation_errors` an array and push the result of your validation into the array. If you don't check for failed validations (i.e. get rid of the `!` in your first `if` statement), the `validation_errors` array will contain `true` only if `validateForm` returns true:

```
var validation_errors = [];
if(validateForm($(this))) {
    validation_errors.push(false);
}
else {
   var $input_container = $(this).parents('.input');
   $input_container.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
}
if(validationErrors.length > 0) {
    //Do some actions
}
```

Alternatively (as I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do), you could just use a string:

```
var validation_errors = "";
if(validateForm($(this))) {
    validation_errors = "true";
}
else {
   var $input_container = $(this).parents('.input');
   $input_container.removeClass('success').addClass('error');
}
if(validation_errors = "true") {
    //Do some actions
}
```

Comment: if the array is called validation_errors I would expect to push false when the validation passed. Apart from that, your code looks strangely familiar ;) Or are you just a slow typist?

Comment: Oops yes, good point. Although it makes no difference what is pushed, because we only care that the array length is greater than 0. I've changed it to `false` though. And you're right, it does look similar to yours! I think I'm just a slow typist (and SO didn't show me the usual "new answers posted" message before I posted this, otherwise I've have seen yours and given up!)

Comment: That makes it doubly wrong. You do not want to push anything if validation passes if you test the length for errors

Comment: like mplungjan points out i only want to do things when validation do not pass.